# What to do about old imported posts that have poor answers?

Tags: discussion, migration

U&L has recently acquired [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10893/what-did-ken-thompson-mean-when-he-said-id-spell-create-with-an-e) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever) from Stack Overflow that have highly upvoted answers (one has our 6th [most](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=isaccepted%3a0) [upvoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=isaccepted%3a1) answer). We simply don't have the voting power to [take such voting into our own hands](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/).

These are the only two examples I know of; most migrated posts are recent enough that we can fix them. But I fear there are more to come. While it's generally accepted that [old posts should normally not be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84395/should-i-flag-ancient-questions-that-need-closing-migrating), and migration to U&L requires moderator intervention, the [flagging campaign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/easy-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-comments-for-flagging-purposes) going on at SO means that moderators have a lot of work and will make mistakes now and then.

What can we do about this?

- Accept that life is life, there will be duds, downvote 40 into 35 and move on?
- Close the problematic questions? (On the one hand, it shouldn't have been migrated here. On the other hand, it could have been asked here.)
- [Lobby really hard for vote counts to be reset to 0 on migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions), which [already happens for negatively voted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6615/reset-negative-vote-counts-on-migrated-questions)?

Comment: Regarding *ole offtopic posts should not be migrated*, there is hardly community consensus given the one example you cited. I don't like the policy BTW.

Comment: That reset of the downvote was because the downvote was for offtopic-ness.

Comment: @Tshepang: I've seen other questions on MSO with the same conclusion, I just suck at finding posts on MSO.

Comment: @Gilles: I don't know if you are looking for votes, but personally I like the idea of voting to reset to 0 on migration. After all, it was not voted on here. I also assume that the reputation is not taken away on migration from the people who got it? That is the way SX seems to work, reputation once granted is not taken away. Though if that is the case, I wonder what the record points to once the questions have been migrated.

Comment: @Faheem: On the contrary, reputation *is* taken away, and that's the way SE generally works. For example, if a user is deleted, all his/her votes are taken away as well. For performance reasons, this may not happen immediately, only when a recalc is performed.

Comment: @Gilles: If you think the answer is poor, I think it would be legitimate (though others might disagree) to post a comment pointing out the problems with the answer. In such a case, I for one, would be interested. And thank you for the clarification about reputation. I guess I had a mistaken impression.

Answer (score 4):

There is another (probably controversial) approach.

Add your own (correct) answer - and if it garners more than say 20 upvotes *from U&L members* then you delete the incorrect/misleading answer(s) and *this* communities votes prevail.[1]

You would probably need to include some sort of explanation in your answer to the effect that the migrated question is under assessment by the U&L community and the migrated answers may be deleted if they are considered incorrect.

[1] The reverse could equally apply and you establish a threshold of downvotes on migrated answers to delete them...

Answer (score 3):

> #### Warning: this answer may not be correct

With your edit powers, leave a big note on top of the post. That should attract enough attention and render the vote almost moot.

Comment: I don't like that because it feels too aggressive against the answerer, and disproportionate (the answer is not top-notch, but it's not wrong either, just not very good). And it doesn't solve the problem of vote skew compared to answers on other questions.

Comment: I'm actually leaning towards *migration should reset all voting*.

Comment: @Tshepang: [So am I, more and more.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions)

Comment: @gil this would strip all rep from the question, which would lead to some pissed-off users. I think your warning is ok if you remove "sucks" so I will edit your post :)

Comment: @Jeff: I'll take good content over happy users any day. I don't notice authors of migrated posts rushing to create an account on U&L, either, though I guess this would only happen on their next rep recalc.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: good edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think questions' score should be reset. Does not matter what happens to the points on the original site, when they enter a new site, that site's current preference should rule (I assume people with higher reps have access to that? or the site creators). Should be 0 whether they where positive or negative to begin with. I also think the poster should be sent a mail with the details : new url etc

Comment: Unfortunately, [that feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions) was declined.

Comment: well there is always next year